# Flutter esys_flutter_share and image picker saver not working

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to download an image and the save image. It’s downloading the image but it’s not opening the share. What am I missing here. I am using this package `esys_flutter_share 1.0.2`
and `image_picker_saver 0.3.0`

```
void onImageDownLoad(Product product, isLoading) async {
  final String text = "${product.name}\n\n${product.description}";
  var request = await HttpClient().getUrl(Uri.parse(product.image));
  var response = await request.close();
  isLoading = true;
  Uint8List bytes = await consolidateHttpClientResponseBytes(response);
  var filepath = await ImagePickerSaver.saveFile(fileData: bytes);
  final ByteData newBytes = await rootBundle.load(filepath);
  isLoading = false;
  await Share.file('ESYS AMLOG', 'amlog.jpg', bytes, 'image/jpg',
      text: text);
}
```

Comment: I'm not totally familiar with these libraries so just some pointers to debug. Does newBytes get filled up with bytes after rootBundle.load()? Does ImagePickerSaver wait until the file save is done before it returns or does it return a filepath while the file save happens in parallel? Does the file get saved to disk? Finally why are you saving the file then loading it from disk again when you already have the bytes you need? Why not just pass fileData to Share.file?

Comment: Thank you.The imagepickersaver is a future and need to be complete before share is called.

Answer (score 0):

So finally figured it out imagePicker saver is a future and need to be completed before the share is called.So I added whenComplete.

```
void onImageDownLoad(Product product, isLoading) async {
          isLoading = true;
          final String text = "${product.name}\n\n${product.description}";
          var req = await HttpClient().getUrl(Uri.parse(product.image));
          var response = await req.close();
          isLoading = false;
          Uint8List bytes = await consolidateHttpClientResponseBytes(response);
          await ImagePickerSaver.saveFile(fileData: bytes).whenComplete(() {
            EsysShare.Share.file('ESYS AMLOG', 'amlog.jpg', bytes, 'image/jpg',
                text: text);
          });
        }
```